# take variable value separately from laravel 5 lists?

Tags: php, html, dom, laravel-5

I pass list of value using my controller.I pass this list to combo box.

This is my code:

```
$fees = Fee::lists('feeCode', 'feeName');
```

I want to set 'feeName' value set to my combo-box, but current way I can set  only feeCode.

This is my GUI  code:

```
  <div class="form-group">
        <label>Fee Code</label>         

        {!! Form::select('fee_id', $fees, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
  </div>
```

I print out put of mu `$fees` array .

This is output

```
{"car parking":"F001","membership fee":"F002"}
```

I want to visible 'feeName' in my comboBox and when Click form submit button feeCode pass as it value. please , wish some one help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reorder the other way around in the Fee::lists

```
$fees = Fee::lists('feeName','feeCode');
```

This will display the feeName in combobox and feeCode will be used as the value